# wiring an Eaton 200 amp box adding a 30 breaker. need to know where the neutral is connected

Tags: wiring

Eaton 200 amp breaker box, adding 30 amp breaker for 110v system. Not sure where the neutral is connected. Can you shed some light?

Comment: a) Generally "next to all the other neutrals" - just look for the white wires... b) 30A 110V is a little unusual (though at all impossible) - more typically it is 15A or 20A 110V (more commonly called 120V, but that's all the same stuff) and when you start getting up to 30A more typically that is along with 240V (e.g., for a dryer or water heater). c) a picture of your existing panel would help **a lot**

Comment: "Eaton" is never enough to describe an Eaton panel.  We need to know Eaton CH (which has a distinctive beige panel color with matching beige breaker trip handles, and 3/4" breakers) versus Eaton BR (which is a gray cabinent with black 1" breakers) versus *occasionally* some other kind.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the panel in question? There are several different possible panel configurations (CH vs BR, PoN vs standard neutral) as well as multiple generations of hardware in play here...

Answer (score 3):

The neutral or white wire goes to one of the silver busses in the panel. If this is a main panel it won’t matter which one if a sub panel one will have all the white wires the other will have all the bare or green wires follow what they did before. 120v 30 amp is not a common residential circuit you are using 10 gauge wires I hope. And the device will be listed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the breaker.

- If it's a 2-pole GFCI breaker, the neutral goes to the breaker, and the breaker pigtail goes to the neutral bar.
- If it's a 2-pole plain breaker, the neutral goes to the neutral bar.

The neutral bar is a closely packed row of screws which capture wires underneath them. There will be a bunch of other white wires also going to this bar.  It will be immediately obvious.

In some cases, the neutral bar will be the same thing as the ground bar, and all neutrals and grounds will be clumped onto the same bar.  DO NOT DO THIS unless you see all other circuits also doing this!

In some cases there is a neutral and not a ground bar.  This happens when the wiring is done in metal conduit, and the grounding is via the metal conduit.  Then ground to the panel chassis or a ground bar (which would be empty), you can buy retrofit ground bars for most panels for $5-ish.

### Receptacles

If this is going to a receptacle, it needs to be a NEMA 14-30 (4-prong) type receptacle.  You are not allowed to install the obsolete/dangerous NEMA 10-30 (3-prong) which has no ground.  If you are hooking up a dryer and the dryer came to you with a NEMA 10-30 cord and plug, then **change the cord and plug to NEMA 14** while removing the neutral-ground jumper on the dryer.

However, if your appliance comes with a NEMA 6-30 plug, you are allowed to install a NEMA 6-30 receptacle instead of 14-30; it'll be grounded and you won't use the neutral.

If you absolutely, insist on wiring it 3-wire without ground, then *still* use a NEMA 14-30 socket and plug, and fit a 2-pole GFCI breaker in the panel.   Label the socket "GFCI Protected / No Equipment Ground".

### Wait, did you say 110V?

A 110/120V circuit that is 30A is extremely rare.  The only legitimate use I have seen is in TT30 sockets for small travel trailers.   Don't misuse a 30A breaker where a 15A or 20A breaker should be used, like powering common lighting and receptacle circuits. Just learn how loads work and act smartly, don't just overload to the point of a house fire.

Therefore I have assumed you're dealing with a 240V load like a dryer that uses two (opposite) 110V circuits at the same time to get 240V. It uses a 2-pole breaker.

Comment: Actually, a NEMA 10-30 would defeat the GFCI protection I reckon (as the receptacle's yoke/backbox would be tied to the N/G terminal)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Good eye, I blew that.